# April CU on App and 2 WFEs

Tags: cumulative-update

SharePoint Server 2010
SharePoint Foundation 2010

We have 1 app server and 2 wfe. Which order April CU should be installed?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you are already at least running SP1 on all machines, you should simply install the binaries on all machines WITHOUT running already SharePoint Wizard as it finishes (Un-check at the end of the installation) - order is not really important, but you could go for the APP server 1st, followed by the WFE.

Once you have the same level of updates physically and successfully installed, then you should start the Configuration Wizard on your APP server, which will push updates in the databases too. Again APP followed by WFE.

Be aware that this might require you to try twice for Configuration Wizard on your Application Server and also that you would need to manually start the User-Profile service after rebooting machines!

Unless your farm is not yet configured (e.g. you have not created any Service Applications), i would suggest you to avoid running the Service Configuration Wizard at the end.